# Gradle cannot resolve my private bintray artifact

Tags: gradle, repository, private, bintray, jcenter

I have setup a private repo, package etc.. where I have uploaded my JAR
on bintray UI it says I need to set this in my gradle

```
maven {
            url  "http://xxx.bintray.com/Test"
            credentials {
                username 'xxx'
                password '<api key>'
            }
        }
```

which I have done (In have taken the PAI key in my profile). and then I have added my dependency:

compile(group: 'com.mypackage', name: 'the-name', version: '0.4.8', ext: 'jar', classifier: '')

But when I synch my gradle it says it cannot find com.mypackage:the-name:0.4.8

Is there something else to setup to be able to pull my lib?

Answer (score 2):

While it is absolutly possible to do with Bintray UI, maven repositories are really strict with the file paths and pom locations, hence, I suggest to try deploying the artifacts to your Bintray private repository with gradle. You also have to supply metadata like pom file of the jar.
This is of course in case you have access to the code.

Maybe we could help more if you would upload some screenshots of your repo structure.

maybe this could help:
https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/formats/formats_mavenrepositories.html

Comment: Oh I see. I have uploaded the jar manually and didn't follow these rules you linked. I'm going to to try doing this directly from gradle then